# Current Density Boundary Conditions and its Implications

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-current, electrical-resistance, boundary-conditions

According to Ohm's Law, one can say $ \overline{J} =\sigma \overline{E} $ if the field is in a conductor, and $ \overline{J} =0 $ if it's in empty space.

Now if we take the surface of a conductor and the current is stationary, it follows that the current density is tangent to the surface. Therefore the field is also tangent to the surface.

If we take an e.m.f. generator which sets the two bases of a cylindrical conductor to a given potential it follows the field associated with that potential is uniform in the conductor, because you specify the potential on the boundaries, the two bases, and $ \frac{\partial V}{\partial n} =0 $ being it the normal derivative to the surface, and is uniquely determined by Laplace equation.

The thing I don't understand is this latter condition. The fact that the current doesn't flow in empty space seems to imply that the external field imposed by the generator has somehow to adapt to the geometry of the conductor.

If you take out the conductor and are left with the two bases at the potentials specified, the field is clearly more complex, and is not uniform in the same volume without the conductor. So what is that changes the field of the generator from when there is a conductor in which flows a current and when there isn't? Unless all these boundaries conditions are self contained in the hypothesis of the generator, I don't see a reason why the generator has to behave differently.

Another point is that the charge in the conductor could arrange itself on the surface of the conductor once the generator imposes the field in such a way that the field (which has now two sources, the generator and some charge that appeared from the conductor) is tangent to the surface of the conductor, but in this case, it doesn't have to be null outside the conductor in its normal component ($ \sigma \overline{E}_{in}  \cdot \overline{n}  =0  \overline{E}_{out} \cdot \overline{n}  $ the equation allows for any value of the exterior normal component), and therefore a surface charge density would appear on the surface of the cylinder that basically "fixes" things inside the conductor. Is this what happens?

(This is very similar as when you have a discontinuity in the resistivity of the conductor that forces a surface charge density on the surface where the resistivity changes, that also influences the field in the conductor. It all follows from the discontinuity of the electrostatic field which follows from the continuity of the current density because we make the hypothesis of a stationary current).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly. When you close the conductor, the charges arrange themselves in a way that they make a constant electric field through a conductor. So, the total electric field becomes the sum of that one produced by the battery plus that one produced by the arranged charges. This arrangement keeps the terminals with the same voltage, respecting the boundary conditions. Note that these electrons being placed at specific regions depends not only on the voltage between terminals but also on the geometry of the conductor. For example, some electrons are going to accumulate in a curve creating a repulsion to the moving electrons and making them deviate from their direction.